# Returning promise of then not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic/AngularJs to set default colors in my app.

I have setup a service for this that returns an object.

I have also setup the promise in my controller but i'm getting "ThemeColors.setColor of then is not a function"

Controller

```
.controller('ColorCtrl', function($scope, $location, ThemeColors) {

  $scope.mmAsideColor = ThemeColors.setDefaultColors.asideColor; 
  $scope.setColor = function(appColor){
    ThemeColors.setColor(appColor)
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
})
```

Service

```
.factory('ThemeColors', function() {

      return {
        setDefaultColors:{
          "backgroundColor": "mm-royal",
          "asideColor": "mm-royal",
          "buttonColor": "button-royal"
        },
        setColor: function(appColor){
          return {
            "asideColor": "The Color is" + appColor
          }
          //"asideColor": "mm-"+appColor,
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: In order to use `then`, your method needs to return a promise. Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your factory needs to return a promise, but you are returning just the result, so you don't need then,

```
$scope.setColor = function(appColor){     
        $scope.data = ThemeColors.setColor(appColor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works...Is a promise not needed here in this instance then? Can you explain?

Comment: I thought I was calling a function and sending a parameter and "Then" I need to return its output

Answer (score 0):

As you make a factory service that not returns a promise call.In your controller you are using `then` method that is not required. If factory returned a promise then you will use `then` method

Try this without then

```
$scope.setColor = function(appColor){     
        $scope.data = ThemeColors.setColor(appColor);
}
```

Promise is like you are querying some data from database and wait for the result either it would be resolve or reject